# Orbit + Clearing Lightbox

Tags: zurb-foundation, lightbox, orbit

Is it impossible to have a orbit slider and a clearing lightbox within?
So that I can slide the image carousel and when I click or tab on a image the lightbox opens? So what can I do to force it?

```
<!doctype html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <div class="orbit-container">
                    <ul class="example-orbit clearing-thumbs" data-orbit data-clearing>
                        <li>
                            <a href="img/galerie/tattoo/colored/col.jpg">
                                <img src="img/galerie/tattoo/colored/col.jpg" alt="slide 1" />
                                <div class="orbit-caption">
                                    Caption One.
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="img/galerie/tattoo/colored/col2.jpg">
                                <img src="img/galerie/tattoo/colored/col2.jpg" alt="slide 2" />
                                <div class="orbit-caption">
                                    Caption Two.
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="img/galerie/tattoo/colored/col3.jpg">
                                <img src="img/galerie/tattoo/colored/col3.jpg" alt="slide 3" />
                                <div class="orbit-caption">
                                    Caption Three.
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/function.js"></script>
        <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>    
        <script>
            $(document).foundation();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

my js file to handle the slider crash the slider. syntax fail?

```
$(document).foundation({
    orbit: {
        animation: 'slide',
        navigation_arrows: true,
        slide_number: false,
        bullets: false, 
        timer: false, 
        variable_height: false,
        swipe: true
    }
});
```

Comment: I am very interested in this answer as well. I want the "carousel" in the lightbox to autoslide and be treated like an orbit. If I find a solution I'll post it here.

Comment: Unfortunately Foundation Clear Lightbox and Orbit Carousel don't mix because the lightbox hides and unhides images as people click on the images in the small little "carousel" at the bottom and it doesn't wrap around. Your best bet would be to use a third party lightbox that will be better suited to carousels. Lightbox2 works well (although it doesn't autoslide). I also found this: http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/raOeez/ which uses Javascript to make a carousel. I simply added attributes to hide and unhide two different views carousel and grid. Messy, but it works.